# Redirect www.subdomain.domain.org to domain.org

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What I would like, is to redirect **www.subdomain.domain.org** to **domain.org** using the same .htaccess in both websites.
I already have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.org/ [L,R=301]
```

which redirects everything that is *not* **domain.org** to **domain.org**, though, it is not redirecting when the URL starts with **www**.
I have tried many other things but it seems like .htaccess cannot detect if the URL starts with **www** or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your rewrite rule is fine (and you already know this because it works). The reason it doesn't work for `www.subdomain.domain.org` is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, I have have found a fix for this.
It requires you to edit the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.domain.org.conf`   And have a new `<VirtualHost *:80>` (unless you already have one specifically for www.subdomain.domain.org) with inside of it:

```
ServerName www.subdomain.domain.org
Redirect permanent / http://subdomain.domain.org/
```

Which will then redirect www.subdomain.org to subdomain.org.
(Apache2 reload may be required, and can help you if you to see if you have any syntax errors)